# Lambda confusion in Kotlin, it == x vs equals(x)

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda, equals

I'm doing a simple test to understand why my code wasn't working.

```
    val v = listOf("1", "2", "2", "3")
    assertThat((v.filter { equals("2") }).size , `is`(2))
```

it fails with reason "size is 0"

but when I change it for:

```
    val v = listOf("1", "2", "2", "3")
    assertThat((v.filter { it == "2" }).size , `is`(2))
```

In Java I could do:

```
.filter(Objects::equals)
```

It returns the expected result. Anybody can understand why is this behaviour???

Comment: When you call `equals("2")` inside your filter, what it's **actually** calling is `this.equals("2")`.  That should make it clear why it doesn't work as expected.  Note that there are some [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html) where the object reference is `this` instead of `it`.  In those instance, the `equals("2")` code would work.  But in the case of `filter()`, the object is scoped as `it`.

Comment: @Jordan thank you now I get it, silly me! It's about the scope

Comment: Kotlin made right step to force explicit conversions. But implicit receivers has become yet another issue that many new programmers struggle with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to write is

```
    assertThat((v.filter { it.equals("2") }).size , `is`(2))
```

although note that IntelliJ will immediately suggest substituting the `equals` call with `==` if you have the 'Can be replaced with binary operator' inspection enabled.

Also, no you wouldn't be able to write this specific call as `.filter(Objects::equals)` in Java, because static `Objects#equals` takes 2 parameters, while the method `filter` provides only 1 to its lambda argument. But you still can use function references in Kotlin too (with the appropriate functions for the lambda expected). For instance, you could filter all non-blank strings like this:

```
    val v = listOf("1", "", "2", "   ", "\t", "3")
    println(v.filter(String::isNotBlank))
```